# Remove bookmarks in PDF created by RMarkdown

Tags: r

When I knit a PDF using RMarkdown, it automatically creates bookmarks in the PDF file from any headers I use.

For example a "bookmark" in the PDF is created when I do:

### this is a header 2

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to modify the latex template.

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex#L105

Set `bookmarks=false` at that line above. Then save as mytemplate.tex file to your working directory, and use this option in your front matter:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: mytemplate.tex
```

Comment: Hmm.  I tried that and it doesn't seem to have worked unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, according to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133303/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-you-pdf-latex-file), the bookmarks = false option has to be set at the package loading line (lines 98 and 102 in the template). Sorry about that I should have tested it before answering.